# function with narrowed return type

Tags: typescript

See complete example in the TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAREAXESDeAoJBSEAHjAPYBO6RwArmEgCoCeMyehnSAyuhQJbAA5gBp8XAgElg6MRIIAxADZkM4ggF8A3LnVIQAIyh8E1eEpBQoSAILxEVygCFL7PZ3hlgxirXjpKAAp3eRgKMnQIfwgAE30YmIpoKAAuJB9BURCJMIioyLj%20KF4Mfng0gzIyJQgQYCQAXiQAMxAlKAgAShwNPWykXMjouIB9JJAYwM60jOEcJCT0Wgp6gCIScBga1a0kXs5evRJyKiRzS2teAWE7ByhKImJI4BjrW%20TnVxx%209FYINJYbAAdFdMo0mH8QXxMjp5GcvD4-AEKIEJolkjNocIREgiiV0GUKlUanVwa12l1vnDOFBaGwUWiklYcXjMAT4J1YfJ9vJxpNpuksUJ5otlvV0AALIpAsa1fm7HmaXScQw%20UxnCxWJAAOXoBggFHejgoj2er1s9g%20FBcHSp8k83j4SKCjIxguuolxxTZhKQlWqtXqTXJHW6HGpBFp9NRCSZUBZ3tKHK5EkVXEG%20Vi%20iMJn8SBGcAoHUCADc2rR-u7MgK6GB9RQdP0%20YEoBKyLQlDEAGptfgxDAQbUgbVEgOkppOrppWv1u0R0UrJCS6UFkBFiCBZdQGXNzqc-ppw6cY6UMya6zSdBG%204mkhm6y6usG68PcMSX5sAGQy-gwEQIGXimXAOoi-gurGbqzJ6rJJqOJJBi0bShnO1JRgaMbosyXr4mU%205wmmnAZsM%20aFsWZZKBWmIejWeoGihcILvUpEQJepblhAOIAIwAAx4dyehpkcpCnhqFxIMoqhXpaxqmhALwPrRhrSTe9GEB%20lZ-gBMi-t%20MhAR4CJOmBDIQVYVGZAmOHlH6xKBmSSGUm%20qF0uhrpYTB7J8am-REQUJFrmR7HmcINFPiaTkMRASyLsxEkYGxFFdPphCHsqhAnqc6kWncDxNKCNzKQ8AA%20SCXi%20JolXFUk5Q2aUEBlZ5idIMQkLE5UADyMLJ8nZVaAB8qkECBRnIsEEYEGE-BlpE%20iFRQAL9GGex1Vwzatu2nY9kofYDkOI42WOCGTgKABKUVin%20nUANqrHyqwALoDRF8gAPQvUw3DwmAMD8DUJoxGQ0DAAA5NQTLVCWyDqdYEoGsgACOtD8DN20ANbIAA7hAwNxGjUNkEC-ScIxS5StuCA1UCa1th23a9v2kR7V5XCpcewmZX8vVWLEl02ANTQ2N15rNa1MQdYIzR0YwA0APxIGd0XAJdjA3Xdj1IGkgt3nJ5rlUgcsKxdfztTYqtyg9A3ThAkO1UJJzUM0tDAP4-BeEgYAgDAjBkNesQm0LbxzTikgB7YSAlSLxBtXNJt9X1qJpJIAq%20zEl2SE9-RvfoQggIIpPIIwn2eN9v10R0EBgNYARIOjEAwEufzWAY4QTEgGOw-UIfLsAqOlTXwBkBjbcShgpXAwwAOZEC09Nudi4gFTcpTEBvS9EAA).

I have two basic types for the model of my application that accesses raw data: `Accessor` and `IndexedAccessor<A extends Accessor>`. They all have `read()` functions that can return a particular primitive type (`number` and `string` for now). For this reason they are a discriminated union instead of subclasses. I'm trying to write code that is able to map model objects (aggregates of accessors) to DTO objects (same properties, but with the raw values coming from accessors).

```
export type AccessedType<A> = A extends IndexedAccessor<infer T> ? ReturnType<T["read"]> :
                              A extends Accessor ? ReturnType<A["read"]> : never;
export function mapToAccessed<A extends Accessor, I extends A | IndexedAccessor<A>>(a: I): AccessedType<I> {
        return a.read();
    }
```

Typescript issues the following error: `Type 'string | number | ReturnType<A["read"]>' is not assignable to type 'AccessedType<I>'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AccessedType<I>'.ts(2322)`

I tried putting square brackets in the conditional parts of `AccessedType`, or just making the return type of `mapToAccessed` be `ReturnType<I["read"]>`, but none of these helped.

Can someone please show me how to formulate this properly, so that I can get such a generic static function, that takes an accessor of some type, and can return the corresponding type? If possible, I'd like to avoid coupling with the set of accessors in the sense that I don't want to write if statements, switch cases for something which is already conceptually typed.

On the flip side, could it be that the type system is lacking here? Could TS be made smarter in this manner? If not, where is my logical pitfall?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NDP76N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to a snippet in the playground that exhibits the behavior I find problematic.

Comment: It's a design limitation, see [ms/TS#44049](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44049) among others. Your choices here would probably be to just use type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqE6Jm), or to refactor so that the generic type is the one coming out of `read()` and not the thing with a `read()` method, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w246bm)... which is much simpler for the compiler to read about.  Would an answer to that effect meet your needs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in comments, this can't be done this way, because of typescript's [design limitations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44049). I will be working around this with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).